# Is it possible to tokenize feature on the fly while training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp

I have CSV file with feature column (string) and multiple label columns (multi-label classification). Dataset is too big to fit into memory, so I have to load this using [make_csv_dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset) with specified batch size. The issue is that I don't know how to tokenize the feature column without overloading the memory, can I implement a DataProvider which will tokenize the data on the fly while training? Then I can tokenize it batch by batch so memory is not an issue.

Comment: Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784011/scikit-learn-fitting-data-into-chunks-vs-fitting-it-all-at-once) can help.

Comment: Hi pbartkow,
Could you please specify the problem faced in make_csv_dataset

Answer (score 0):

You can tokenize on the fly using "pyspark(in python)", and "sparkly" (in R)
Please refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53579444/efficient-text-preprocessing-using-pyspark-clean-tokenize-stopwords-stemming) and this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.Tokenizer.html) to solve your problem.